# Retreive commits that got detached from the main tree without tags or branches present

Tags: git, addition, restore

My commits got detached from the main tree without tags or branches present.
is there any way to retreive them?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up first running bash-command:'find . * | less' from the .git folder in the root of the project.
Then I found a folder that its name was something like 'lost&found' spotting in the first command.
I got into it and recieved all the id's of these commits.
Checkout them and then retreived the lost data.